# Access request.user in modelForm

Tags: python, django, modelform

If i am using model forms where my views.py looks like:

```
def dog_image_upload(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = DogImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
        else:
            form = DogImageForm(user)
        return render_to_response("dog-image-upload.html", {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

And in model.py i want to do this:

```
class DogImageForm(ModelForm):
    dogs = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Dog.objects.filter(user=request.user))
    class Meta:
        model = ResultsUpload
        fields = ['dogs','image']
```

However, i am having trouble trying to send the user to model.py
Help on this would be awesome and point worthy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would have to do it in the modelform's `__init__`

```
class DogImageForm(ModelForm):
    dogs = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Dog.objects.none())
    class Meta:
        model = ResultsUpload

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DogImageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['dogs'].queryset = Dog.objects.filter(user=user)
```

and during the initialization of the form,

```
form = DogImageForm(user=request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, its working with your solution without errors now, however, the list has no values in it. Is that because of the query is not finding values to return?

Comment: yeah.. to verify that, in the django shell , run this query (`Dog.objects.filter(user=user)`) with the specified user

Comment: Ahh noob mistake my issue is `request.user` is from `django.contrib.auth.models import user` where the user field in the `Dog` model is a link to another model `UserProfile`. I should be better with my variable names. Thanks @karthikr, i couldn't understand other peoples solutions on this problem, yours is awesome.

Comment: @Alex Stewart I'm in the same case but I use my **form** in a **class based create view** and I do `form_class=DogImageForm` , how to initialize my **form** to give it the **request.user** as argument