# ModelForm does not like receiving an instance

Tags: python, django, modelform

What i am trying to do is update an existing row in the Dog model using Django forms but i am coming across an error.

I am getting this error:

```
__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'user'
```

because django thinks there is an issue here:

```
form = DogImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user, instance=instance)
```

My model.py is

```
class DogImageForm(ModelForm):
    dogs = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Dog.objects.none())
    class Meta:
        model = Dog
        fields = ['dogs','image']

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DogImageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
        self.fields['dogs'].queryset = Dog.objects.filter(user=userprofile)
```

And my view.py is:

```
def dog_image_upload(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':

            userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            instance = Dog.objects.get(id=str(request.POST['dogs']))#user=userprofile,

            form = DogImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user, instance=instance)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                reader = csv.reader(request.FILES['file'])
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/members-dogs/')
        else:
            form = DogImageForm(user=request.user)
        return render_to_response("dog-image-upload.html", {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

I was originally stuck on passing the request.user using modelForm here [Access request.user in modelForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768563/access-request-user-in-modelform)

If anyone has a solution to fixing this i would be super happy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing request.POST as positional argument user, request.user as keyword argument user. You're doing something like following:

```
>>> def f(user, *args, **kwargs): pass
...
>>> f('post', user='user')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'user'
>>> f('user', 'post')
```

Instead do following:

```
form = DogImageForm(request.user, request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
```

Comment: @AlexStewart, You're welcome. I did that mistake many times ;)